# How can a Microsoft Word binary be stored in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, ms-word, hive

Question from a relative Hadoop/Hive newbie:  How can I pass the contents of a Microsoft Word (binary) document as a parameter to a Hive function?

My goal is to be able to provide the full contents of a binary file (a Microsoft Word document in my particular use case) as a binary parameter to a UDTF.  My initial approach has been to slurp the file's contents into a staging table and then provide it to the UDTF in a query later on, and this was how I attempted to build that staging table:

```
create table worddoc(content BINARY);
load data inpath '/path/to/wordfile' into table worddoc;
```

Unfortunately, there seem to be newlines in the Word document (or something acting enough like newlines) that results in the staging table having many rows instead of a single comprehensive blob, the latter of which is what I was hoping for.  Is there some way of ensuring that the ingest doesn't get exploded into multiple rows?  I've seen similar questions here on SO regarding other binary data like image files, so that is why I'm guessing it's the newlines that are tripping me up.

Failing all that, is there a way to skip storing the file's contents in an intermediary Hive table and just provide the content directly to the UDTF at invocation time?  Nothing obvious jumped out during my search through Hive's built-in functions, but maybe I am missing something.

Version-wise, the environment is Hive 0.13.1 and Hadoop 1.2.1 (although upgrades to both are pending).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack-y workaround but what I ended up doing is this:

1) base64 encode the binary document and put the encoded file into HDFS

2) In Hive:

```
CREATE TABLE staging_table (content STRING);
LOAD DATA INPATH '/path/to/base64_encoded_file' INTO TABLE staging_table;
CREATE TABLE target_table (content BINARY);
INSERT INTO target_table SELECT unbase64(content) FROM staging_table;
```

Theoretically this should work for any arbitrary binary file that you'd want to squish into Hive this way.  A gotcha to watch out for is to make sure your base64 encoding implementation produces a single-line file (my OS X base64 utility produces 1-line output, while the base64 utility in a CentOS 6 VM I was using produced hundreds of lines) - if it doesn't, you can manually glue it together before putting it into HDFS.